# Why does doubling just puts the number twice?

Tags: ruby

So I'm real new to Ruby and I'm not sure exactly how things work. I've been working through the Codecademy and experimenting with some things. Anyway, I want to use a yield statement to double a number I feed into the terminal. Here's what I have

```
 def double(i)
  puts "Type a number!"
  yield(i)
  puts "Look at that! It's doubled!"
end

double(gets.chomp) {|i| puts i*2}
```

Weirdly, rather than doubling it, this is returning the number twice, i.e. if I input 3, I get 33, not 6.  When I replace the *gets.chomp* with an integer, it doubles it properly though, so Somehow my *gets.chomp* must be flawed, but I have no idea how. Any advice would help immensely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `.to_i` function since `gets.chomp` returns text.

```rb
 def double(i)
  i = i.to_i
  puts "Type a number!"
  yield(i)
  puts "Look at that! It's doubled!"
end

double(gets.chomp) {|i| puts i*2}
```

*tried and tested in codecademy*

Comment: Exactly. Compare `'3'*2` vs. `3*2` in `irb`. The first is `String#*` and the latter is `Integer#*`.

Comment: That worked out great! Thanks! I assume it's because the Ruby needed to turn it into an integer and I hadn't told it to do that(?)

Comment: @tadman  Thanks! That really helps clear it up!

Comment: Key thing to remember about Ruby is there are only a handful of situations where the fundamental type (Class) of an object will switch automatically. `1 * 2.0` is an example, you get a floating point result, but `'1' * 2` is not, and neither is `1 / 2`. Outside of implicit float conversion, assume you must convert explicitly.

Comment: If you're used to JavaScript or Python or Perl where numbers and strings are in many cases interchangeable, this is absolutely not the case in Ruby. Same as how in Ruby `0` and `''` are truthful in a logical sense, which is very much not the case in many other languages.

Comment: @tadman: "there are only a handful of situations where the fundamental type (Class) of an object will switch automatically" – There is *never* a situation where an object will switch its class, neither automatically nor otherwise. In Ruby, the class of an object is fixed upon creation, it can never change afterwards. There is no Ruby equivalent to Smalltalk's `become:` (which technically does not change the class of an object but makes the object become a different object which can have a different class as well) or Python's `obj.__class__ = SomeClass`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I mean more like `1 + 1.1` (`Integer#+` on `Float`) returns a `Float`, as in the first argument is treated as if it were a float for the purpose of calculation. This *implicit conversion* is extremely rare in Ruby, but super common in other languages like JavaScript or, worse, Perl.